# Spaces between items of a GridView

Tags: android, gridview, space

I'm using a GridView in my code. I have a problem with space.
This is my problem:

[image]

When the text is short no problem, but the problem is when are longer.
I want to get this:

[image]

This is my GridView:

```
<GridView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:divider="@color/transparente"
            android:horizontalSpacing="4dp"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:verticalSpacing="4dp" >
        </GridView>
```

And this is the xml of the elements of the GridView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_title_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text text text text text text"
            android:textColor="@color/blanco"
            android:textSize="@dimen/titulos" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_alarm_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text text text text text text"
            android:textColor="@color/blanco"
            android:textSize="@dimen/contenido" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_alarm_days"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text text text text text text"
            android:textColor="@color/blanco"
            android:textSize="@dimen/contenido" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to use `android: stretchMode = "spacingWidth", "columnWidth" and android: verticalSpacing = "4DP"` ... but without success

I searched for answers, but can not find anything to help me

I appreciate any help

Thanks and regards

Comment: what if you set layout_height of the main LinearLayout of the element to "match_parent" instead of "wrap_content"?

Comment: I already tried that change, but does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must declare the real max size. Setting in root layout any params won't help. You should set it separately in each of child elements.
For example here is my code, please look at this two children elements, they have max possible height and width. I think setting width doesn't matter but I might be in mistake. However the height size must be setted anyway. Please check this out and try in your project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/stub"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:text="text" />
</LinearLayout>
```